# Cross-Origin Request Blocked for POST request from Angular to Web.API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular6

I have a small demo app:

1. Angular on FE (http://localhost:4200/)
2. ASP.Net Core on BE (https://localhost:44333/)

The get requests from FE to BE seems to be working fine.
But the POST request throws:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44333/api/auth/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

The HTTP works fine. The only issue is with HTTPS.

The Postman works fine with the same api method:
[image: Postman]

The Angular service looks like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  baseUrl = 'https://localhost:44333/api/auth/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  login(model: any) {

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model)
      .pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        }
      }));
  }
}
```

On BE side now any origins are allowed:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The sources of the app available on the [github](https://github.com/BorisSokolov/AspCoreAngular2)

The error that is in the console of the dotnet server:

> > ```
> >   Connection id "0HLK56HC2M58N" request processing ended abnormally. System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed,
> > ```
> >
> > see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An
> >     unknown error occurred while processing the certificate    --- End of
> >     inner exception stack trace ---    at
> >     System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter
> >     adapter, Memory`1 buffer)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.AdaptedPipeline.ReadInputAsync(Stream
> >     stream)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken
> >     cancellationToken)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.BeginRead(ValueTask`1&
> >     awaitable)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> >     application)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> >     application) info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[20]
> >           Connection id "0HLK56HC2M58O" request processing ended abnormally. System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed,
> >     see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An
> >     unknown error occurred while processing the certificate    --- End of
> >     inner exception stack trace ---    at
> >     System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter
> >     adapter, Memory`1 buffer)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.AdaptedPipeline.ReadInputAsync(Stream
> >     stream)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken
> >     cancellationToken)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.BeginRead(ValueTask`1&
> >     awaitable)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> >     application)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> >     application) info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[20]
> >           Connection id "0HLK56HC2M58Q" request processing ended abnormally. System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed,
> >     see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An
> >     unknown error occurred while processing the certificate    --- End of
> >     inner exception stack trace ---    at
> >     System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter
> >     adapter, Memory`1 buffer)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.AdaptedPipeline.ReadInputAsync(Stream
> >     stream)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken
> >     cancellationToken)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.BeginRead(ValueTask`1&
> >     awaitable)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> >     application)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> >     application) info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[20]
> >           Connection id "0HLK56HC2M58P" request processing ended abnormally. System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed,
> >     see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An
> >     unknown error occurred while processing the certificate    --- End of
> >     inner exception stack trace ---    at
> >     System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter
> >     adapter, Memory`1 buffer)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.AdaptedPipeline.ReadInputAsync(Stream
> >     stream)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()    at
> >     System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
> >
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> >     application)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> >     application)

Comment: Are you getting exceptions? Error middleware clears all heads (including CORS), so when an exception happens, there are no heads and the request will fail with that message

Comment: Hi @Tseng, the call doesn't reach the actual action in the controller. The action itself seems to be working as Postman gets the correct response with the token

Comment: This doesn't reply the question: Do you have any exceptions in your application during the call? Yes? => fix the exception and the call won't throw CORS error int he browser. Check your log (or the output of the console)

Comment: @Tseng have added the error to the post

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need add [AllowCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.allowcredentials?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method.

Please review this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests) about credentials in cross-origin requests.

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Hi @Alexander. it seems that it doesn't help in my case.

Comment: On your StackTrace i see "An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate". Try to test your app on HTTP protocol. If HTTP works correctly then you have a trouble with HTTPS. In this case please review this [link](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/18.6.php) (Russian blog). I hope it helps...

Comment: The HTTP works correctly. For HTTPS it looks more like an issue on Angular side with headers, etc. As in general the API is available

Answer (score 0):

Allow CORS with wildcard while developing.

```
//Allow CORS, * wildcard only for development period, be specific once done
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
```

Hope this helps :)